# Create automatic data text in sketch

Tags: sketch-app, symbols

I'm trying to make something like "data population" plugin, but without the plugin. 
With Data population I can use a group of information, not just a random name and a random email.

I've tried this: https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/using-the-new-data-feature-in-sketch-52-daee8403cabb
but I don't know how to group the information.

I want to know if there's anyway, using the new Data feature in Sketch, to do this: https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/create-your-own-data-to-use-in-sketch-no-code-required-4aa79d0335cd

Thank you!

[image: Sketch Data]

Comment: Your problem is not very clear: where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried? Where have you failed? Can you [edit] your question to add more details?

Comment: @Luciano thank you for your answer. I hope that I've been more clear now.

Comment: Right now your question is "I have this tutorial, does anyone know if it works?" But have you tried following that second link? It's literally the answer to your question! Why don't you try that and then ask a question here IF it doesn't work??

Comment: I've tried, obvious. the tutorials are different. I'm just asking if there's any way to group data information without the "data population" plugin (or Craft. in sketch only). I don't know how to explain better than this... thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch doesnt have this funcationality but Adobe XD has it for images.

1. Create a container
2. Mark it as "repeat grid"
3. Make so many grid containers you want
4. Drag all your images and drop it onto the repeat grid area
5. Change the text of each repeated container manually

For Sketch you can use these data plugins only. One hacky way to get your own data using the random faces plugin would be if you open the .sketchapp file in an editor of your choice and replace the Rest API URL with your own one to get your own data.